# Run a program from logon batch file accepting yes for UAC

Tags: batch-file, cmd, winlogon

I am trying to set up a log on batch file that runs ccleaner.exe /AUTO at each log on to keep the internet cache and temp files clear. We use a web browser based system that fills up a lot of the user profile's IE temp files.

Here is what I am trying to use in a batch file,

```
cd \
runas /user:localtv /pass:start123 /savecred "c:\CCleaner.exe /AUTO"
PAUSE
```

The thing with this, is that every time it runs, it brings up UAC yes or no. I would like it to not do that.

Is this possible?

Or do you think I should just write a batch file that deletes all the files and folders individually?

Any advice would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not answer the question but might solve your overall problem:

You could use the Windows Task Scheduler to run `CCleaner /AUTO` at every log in.

Simply create an entry as Administrator and get it to run when any user logs in, the UAC will not bother you this time as it will run with admin privileges.

You can find the Task Scheduler by searching for it in the Start menu.

Comment: I was thinking of doing it this way. I want UAC to remain ON.

Comment: Also, I want the web history to be dumped into an xml/csv file before it get's hit by ccleaner. I have to figure out which one would process first. the logon batch file or the scheduled task....I will take a look at my options. Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn UAC off manually, but you can't bypass UAC (at this point in time).

That is the point of UAC - to stop malicious programs from causing havoc with admin permissions.